# Logical Equivalence Derivation (Propositonal Logic)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have some difficulties to derive how one arrives at the RHS by using the common rules for logical equivalences (and yes, the following equivalences are all correct => checked correctness by looking at truth tables)

`(A∧(¬B)) ∨ (B∧(¬C)) ≡ (A∨B) ∧ ¬(B∧C)`

when distributing the LHS:

`(A∨B) ∧ (A∨(¬C)) ∧ ((¬B)∨B) ∧ ((¬B)∨(¬C)) ≡ (A∨B) ∧ ¬(B∧C)`

when applying the tautology + de Morgan's law:

`(A∨B) ∧ (A∨(¬C)) ∧ ¬(B∧C) ≡ (A∨B) ∧ ¬(B∧C)`

Why is the middle part there? It is correct like that as the truth tables are the exact same as in the case of the RHS of the initial formula.

But it shouldn't be there to arrive at the RHS.
I do not know how to get rid of it? I don't see how absorption may apply here.

Does anyone know how to derive it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE :) Since you're new, let me inform you that people can see that a question is answered when you press the green checkmark next to an answer, which indicates that this answer answers your question. So you don't need to write in the title that the question is not answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved very easily using the [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem), which states that:

$(X \lor Y) \land (\neg Y \lor Z)  \land (X \lor Z) \Leftrightarrow  (X \lor Y) \land (\neg Y \lor Z)$

(this law is most easily remembered by going from right to left: with the $(X \lor Y)$ term containing a $Y$, and the $(\neg Y \lor Z)$ term containing a $\neg Y$, you can put together the other parts ($X$ and $Z$) into a new term $(X \lor Z)$ and just add that as a third term.

So with that:

$$(A\land\lnot B)\lor(B\land\lnot C)$$

$$\overset{Distribution}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(A\lor B)\land(A\lor\lnot C)\land(\lnot B\lor B)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C)$$

$$\overset{Tautology}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(A\lor B)\land(A\lor\lnot C)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C)$$

$$\overset{Consensus}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(A\lor B)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C)$$

$$\overset{DeMorgan}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(A\lor B)\land \lnot (B\land C)$$

If you are not allowed to use Consensus in one step, please know that it is easily derived as follows:

$$(X \lor Y) \land (\neg Y \lor Z) \land (X \lor Z)$$

$$\overset{Adjacency}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(X \lor Y) \land (\neg Y \lor Z) \land (X \lor Z \lor Y) \land (X \lor Z \lor \neg Y)$$

$$\overset{Absorption \ x \ 2}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$(X \lor Y) \land (\neg Y \lor Z)$$

Comment: Wow! This looks really nice! Thank you so much! I was really curious about how a textbook arrived at this derivation and tried to solve it myself. Didn't know about this rule!

Comment: @Leon You're welcome! Some of these more advanced rules can make your life a lot easier when doing Boolean Algebra! :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(A\land\lnot B)\lor(B\land\lnot C)&=(A\lor B)\land(A\lor\lnot C)\land(\lnot B\lor B)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C)\\
&=(A\lor B)\land(A\lor\lnot C)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C)\\
&=((A\lor B)\land(A\lor\lnot C))\land((A\lor\lnot C)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C))\\
&=(A\lor(B\land\lnot C))\land((A\land\lnot B)\lor\lnot C)\\
&=(A\land(A\land\lnot B))\lor(A\land\lnot C)\\
&\quad\lor((B\land\lnot C)\land(A\land\lnot B))\lor((B\land\lnot C)\land\lnot C)\\
&=(A\land\lnot B)\lor(A\land\lnot C)\lor(B\land\lnot C)\\
&=(A\land\lnot B)\lor(B\land\lnot B)\lor(A\land\lnot C)\lor(B\land\lnot C)\\
&=((A\lor B)\land\lnot B)\lor((A\lor B)\land\lnot C)\\
&=(A\lor B)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot C)\\
&=(A\lor B)\land\lnot(B\land C)
\end{align}

Comment: Wow. Thanks! This looks way uglier than expected... damn.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You have to apply the law of distributivity as follows:

$(A\wedge\bar B)\vee (B\wedge\bar C) \Longleftrightarrow [(A\wedge\bar B)\vee B]\wedge [(A\wedge\bar B)\vee\bar C]$.

Now apply the law twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We'd then arrive at: (∨)∧(¯∨)∧(∨¯)∧(¯∨¯) ... the tautology with respect to B can then be cancelled out I guess? But then this (∨¯) is still left in the formula even after applying Morgan's law to the last part (¯∨¯)

Comment: Also see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

One wants to use **distributivity** :
$$(X \wedge Y) \vee (Z \wedge T) \equiv  (X \vee Z) \wedge (X \vee T) \wedge (Y \vee Z) \wedge (Y \vee T) $$

> **edited** along with the former - very confusing - notations

In our case, considering that $(B \vee \neg B) \equiv \top$, we get that your formula is equivalent to $(A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee \neg C) \wedge (\neg B \vee \neg C)$. The disturbing middle term $(A \vee \neg C)$ has redundancy with both the left and the right term. It is convenient to duplicate it since $\varphi \wedge \varphi \equiv \varphi$. We get that
$(A\wedge \neg B) \vee (B\wedge \neg C)$ is equivalent to:
$$\big((A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee \neg C) \big) \wedge \big( (A \vee \neg C) \wedge(\neg B \vee \neg C) \big) $$

Now, we factorize (eg.) $A$, using distribution of $\wedge$ over $\vee$ this time :
$$  (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee \neg C)  \equiv  A \vee (B \wedge \neg C)
 $$

$$\vdots$$
$\dots$ From there, use **De Morgan's Law** that asserts that $(\neg B \vee \neg C) \equiv \neg (B \wedge C)$.

> **MOST IMPORTANT EDIT :** Toying around with the formula like that is a ***terrible*** way to solve this exercise. The best is to compute the truth table of both formulas and check that they're identical.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
A & B & C & (A \wedge \neg B) & (B \wedge \neg C) & (A \wedge \neg B) \vee (B \wedge \neg C)  & (A \vee B) & \neg (B \wedge C) & (A \vee B) \wedge \neg (B \wedge C) \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
{} & \vdots & {} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array} $$

Now THAT is guaranteed to work and is left to the reader.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! What about the ∧(∨¬) part after applying the distributivity formula that u stated? It's still there among the other terms (see my edited question)

Comment: @Leon I've been too lazy to try and write it down... Please check this important edit ;)